# Как использовать iframe в Django?

Tags: html, django

При использовании iframe, мне выдает ошибку: Refused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
Как это можно исправить?

```
 <iframe src="{% url 'register' %}" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Настроить этот самый X-Frame-Options https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/clickjacking/

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267383/how-to-configure-x-frame-options-in-django-to-allow-iframe-embedding-of-one-view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

@xframe_options_exempt
def ok_to_load_in_a_frame(request):
    return HttpResponse("This page is safe to load in a frame on any site.")
```